# How to use GRUB as default bootloader while dual booting Win7+ubuntu

Tags: grub2, bootloader, default

I installed windows 7 first and then Ubuntu, booted back into windows and used EasyBCD to use the Windows 7 bootloader for dual booting. So when the system is rebooted Windows bootloader comes up first and once you select Ubuntu then GRUB shows up.

I need to how to make GRUB the default bootloader instead of windows 7's.

Thank you

Comment: see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/88432#88432)

Answer (score 2):

Simple. Boot-repair.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then run Boot-repair by **`sudo boot-repair`** and use "Recommended repair".

GRUB2 will automatically detect windows boot Path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are somewhat of a beginner, you should use [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).